# DIY hypernatrimia test

Tags: blood-tests, sodium

Is there a reliable, accessible blood test kit that can be administered at home to monitor hypernatrimia ?

I understand that because sodium does not produce colored compounds, serum sodium cannot be measured easily at home.  Is this really the case? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?